# How to keep log of a whole day, for complete AWS s3 bucket, in single file?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have `s3` buckets say `xfile`, and say `xlog`.

`xfile` to keep the files, and `xlog` to keep files.

I have one folder as `xlog/data`, and i have also enabled logging for `xfile` with prefix `data`

I have done no extra configuration, everything going on defaults.

So after some time i see logs like this in `data` folder of `xlog`
[image]

It seems like that for every request a separate log file is created.
Is that the expected behaviour?

What i am expecting to have one file for 0000 hrs to 2359 hrs, that contains the complete logs of one single day. For another day, separate file should be created.

What am i missing? or how should i configure this?

Comment: Is this with S3 serving a static website? With a fairly low load? Separate logs are fairly typical in AWS, since logs are written by a variety of servers.

Comment: you may consider s3 service a static file (not even a website).. yes it have fairly low load.. (for experiment).. but expected to have some 2-3k requests per day in near future.. (i want to configure the timeslot for one log file at later stage),, So in basic, i want to know the algo or some logic at what conditions AWS creates a new file or append in a previous log file.

Comment: S3 static website hosting is an explicit feature, which is distinct from standard S3 use. I was trying to work out what logs you were referring to, your question isn't entirely clear on that point - it could've been application logs. AWS creates a new log file when it wants to, all you can do is cater for that and deal with it. If you want to know why, it's probably because S3 has many, many machines serving files, and each machine will create its own log in your S3 log bucket.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

S3 is a distributed system, and this is at least one factor in the large numbers of log files it generates.

Objects in S3 are immutable -- it isn't possible to directly append data to an S3 object, and doing so requires an emulation operation: the bytes of the object must be copied into a new object, followed by the additional data.  This would make logging into a single "growing" daily log file nearly impossible to do at any scale.  The log files are standard S3 objects, so this is likely another reason why the individual files are written as they are.

It isn't one file per request, although it can certainly seem like that on a bucket with low traffic.  Essentially, each log file contains records created prior to its timestamp, but not necessarily records since the last log was written -- a log file can occasionally contain records from hours, days, or weeks ago that have been stranded somewhere inside S3 and have finally been released.  This is rare, but a documented possibility.

Logs for troubleshooting are often needed quickly after the events occur, so it often desirable to receive them as soon as practical, and that is what S3 tends to do.

This is not configurable.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ServerLogs.html

My solution for easy access to logs is an S3 event notification on my log-collecting buckets, which sends a message into an SQS queue.  The queue consumer runs on an EC2 instance with an EBS Cold Storage (sc1) volume.  When each log file is written to the bucket, the queue consumer fetches the file, and derives the date from the filename.  It then parses the log events to determine their HTTP status class, e.g. 2XX, 3XX, 4XX, 5XX, or other/unmatched, and appends each record to a master daily file.  The records with 4xx, 5xx, or unmatched/unexpected are appended to smaller daily files with errors only.  Searching these local files with a tool like `grep` then becomes a trivial task.